# How do I configure Subversion 1.5 support in Xcode?

Tags: svn, xcode

According to the release notes for the iPhone 2.2.1, SDK Xcode now officially supports Subversion 1.5. I've converted my working copy to use the new 1.5 format; however, Xcode now will no longer track changes.  I'm guessing there is somewhere in Xcode that I have to tell it to use the 1.5 format. Has anyone found it yet?

Answer (score 3):

Google is your friend:

http://www.lemonteam.com/blog/2008/12/setting-up-subversion-15-on-xcode/

Please note the errors and caveats in the comments before you go blindly running the code in the tutorial.  I have not tried it myself, so this is not a recommendation; merely the best search result I found.  Like Brock Woolf I use Versions and the command line, and am quite happy with that workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the release notes indicates that Xcode comes with svn 1.5, only that it works with it.

I guess that Xcode uses the already installed svn 1.4. Maybe you have to install svn 1.5 on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried using Xcode's SVN integration and quite frankly, it sucks and I would suggest not using it.

I think you will be much happier with a dedicated Subversion application such as **Versions**, which is my favourite svn app: [www.versionsapp.com](http://www.versionsapp.com)

If you don't want to pay for Versions, there is another free alternative called [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/)

Oh and to answer your question, unfortunately you are going to have to wait until Apple update Xcode to support the new version, which considering their track record with taking 5 years to give us Java 1.6 on Mac, will not likely be in the near future.